# How to add custom console commands?

Tags: phpstorm

In which way can I add in my  PhpStorm 2023.3.1 custom console commands like

```
  php artisan route:list
```

to find and run them by context Shift+Shift keys ?

Comment: Please check this article:
https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/php-specific-command-line-tools.html

(also, "Run command" is Ctrl+Ctrl, not Shift+Shift)